# Facebook Api Login NodeJS Uncaught Exception

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-webkit, nw.js

I have a NW.js application where I need user to login his/her Facebook account to share something. When facebook login popup window appears my application crashes and message shows up on the main window's screen;

```
Uncaught node.js Error

Error: Cannot find module 'TimeSlice'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:273:25)
at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
at require (module.js:378:17)
at window.require (:4:17)
at https://www.facebook.com/login.php?
...
```

I checked the facebook login window's console and those node.js errors were coming from that popup like below;

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: __d is not defined KLwacKO4h5u.js:34
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'TimeSlice' module.js:338
Uncaught ReferenceError: requireLazy is not defined 
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'TimeSlice' module.js:338
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'BigPipe' module.js:338
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'beforePageletArrive' of undefined 
...
```

I searched for the solution and tried to catch all node.js exceptions with code below but it didn't help, exceptions still throwing uncaught. (I know it's wrong but I just wanted to try.)

```
var process = require('process');
if(process) {
    process.on("uncaughtException", function(e) { console.log(e); });
}
```

What am I missing here? Could you show me a way to pass this issue? I want to prevent the app crash when some exceptions happen on external URL's window.

Comment: Did you run npm install?

Comment: Actually I don't have that js modules in my application. Someone told that js modules belongs to Facebook SDK. But my application tries to find them through node.js. Can I disable node.js for that part of the application?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're missing this flag...

> --allow-cross-origin-auth-prompt